# How to install Ubuntu in a PPC ibook g4?

Tags: system-installation

Do Ubuntu live CDs have to be PowerPC to boot into them on an ibook G4 (mid 2005)? I haven't tried yet, but I was wondering because I am thinking of running Ubuntu on it.

Comment: I just loaded Kubuntu 12.04 on my iBook G4. No problems with the installation. My Ethernet, works I haven't tried my Airport wireless yet. System runs about same as OSX.3 did, however, all your apps are new. I've been on the net using Firefox. This seems like a great way to put new life into a old Mac. In the morning I'll work on email and see what else does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must use a PowerPC build to run on a G4 CPU Mac. Also, 10.04 Desktop and 11.04 are end of life, and so unsupported.

Comment: I've seen videos of 12.04 and such on ppc ibooks, how is that possible then?

Comment: There is an alternate install image of Ubuntu for PowerPC at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ which was probably used.

Comment: O.k., thanks! I will look into installing Ubuntu 10.04 PPC onto an ibook G4!

Comment: @jrub again, you should be looking to install 12.04 instead.